# (null) cannot run armv7f in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode6, armv7, ios8.3

When I try to run my application on my iPad (IOS 8.3) from xcode6.3.1, I am getting the following error.  I am using valid architectures **Standard architectures(armv7,armv7s)**. Can anyone tell me why this error occured and what this armv7f means?

[image: Error message]

Comment: What architectures are you building for?  Sounds like you have a typo under Build Settings -> Architectures -> Valid Architectures.

Comment: yes am building valid architectures armv64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: FYI posting images of errors or code [is discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/616644) as it as several drawbacks.

Comment: I got same issue using iPad 3(iOS 9.3.2) with XCode 7.3

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore this message, it is a bug in Xcode. Disconnect and re-connect the device to your computer to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have built the app for the iPad mini and are now trying to run it on a non-mini iPad.